# How do I find the parent directory of a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, directory

Is there some function that returns the parent directory of a file in Perl?

Comment: The suggestion of Cwd::realpath was a good one for some cases, too bad that answer got deleted.

Comment: @Zerobu: provide an example so we know exactly what you are talking about

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a path name, you can use the `dirname` function from [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html).

```
 use File::Basename;
 my $directory = dirname( $path );
```

What do you have as input?

Comment: just a filename without any leading or trailing slashes

Comment: what do you mean by "just a filename"?

Comment: @Zerobu: So it's a relative path. `dirname` will still give you what you want, with the possible exception of files in the current directory - look at the documentation and see for yourself.

Comment: like the name of the file with the extension
Example hello.txt or hello.gif,

Comment: If you just have the filename and nothing else, you're out of luck.

Comment: Also, please update your question with additional information. Don't bury it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the most brilliant brian's method above and if the `$directory` eq "." then replace "." with your currrent working directory.

Comment: You can also use File::Spec to turn relative paths into absolute ones, and clean up various /./ and /../ issues.

Answer (score 0):

Also note [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~kwilliams/Path-Class-0.18/lib/Path/Class.pm), which makes working with paths sane.